# add apostrophe to regex match

Tags: php, regex

Here is my source of text:

```
           $data['DATA_TYPE'] = 'enum('Film Studio','Website','Advertiser','Distributer')';
```

Here is my code:

```
            $data = static::getColumnInfo($resourceClassName, $columnName);
            $data = $data['DATA_TYPE'];
            preg_match('/enum\((.*)\)$/',$data,$matches);
            $vals = explode(',',$matches[1]);
```

Here is the outcome:

```
            0 => string ''Film Studio'' (length=13)
            1 => string ''Website'' (length=9)
            2 => string ''Advertiser'' (length=12)
            3 => string ''Distributer'' (length=13)
```

As you can see, the outcome contains **a quote at the beginning and end** in each index.

I need to modify the regular expression to group by its current operations plus beginning and ending quotes, so i can maintain quotes within but match the expected outside ones.

Comment: How are you generating the "outcome"?  I believe the extra quotes are your output (var_dump() ?).  the length of the string only includes the string and the single quotes you got from within the string in your regex.  you can trim those quotes with trim($input, "'");

Comment: @anubhava string 'enum('Film Studio','Website','Advertiser','Distributer')' (length=56)

Comment: @fbas the outcome comes from exploding by ,

Comment: the outcome i provided. its correct, but i want the apostrophes at the beginning and end of each string to be elminated

Comment: I think that this task may be done without [tag:regex] @jkushner

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
$vals = explode(',', preg_replace("/^'|'$|'(?=,)|(?<=,)'/", "", $matches[1]));
```

i.e. remove single quotes from `$matches[1]` string and then explode using comma.

It will get:

```
print_r ( $vals );
Array
(
    [0] => Film Studio
    [1] => Website
    [2] => Advertiser
    [3] => Distributer
)
```

**Explanation:**

```
/^'|'$|'(?=,)|(?<=,)'/    # regex used for removing single quote
^'                        # quote found at start
'$                        # quote found at end
'(?=,)                    # lookahead, quote followed by a comma
(?<=,)'                   # lookbehind, quote preceded by a comma
```

Comment: right unfortunately that will remove single quotes that are within the string. i need specifically the quotes from the beginning and end only.

Comment: @fbas that won't work either. that would remove the first quote and the last quote only, leaving the entities inside. i need the regex to group by quotes too

Comment: @jkushner: Try my updated code, it will keep single quote within the string now.

Comment: @anubhava can you dissect and explain the regex so i can understand it?

Comment: Added some explanation of `preg_replace` used.